# Facebook Live API Resolution is not 720p during Live

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, streaming, live

I used the facebook live api to upload high quality live stream, but what I can see in facebook live is only 480p or lower resolution during "live".

Only after the live stream is over, turn into vod(replay), it can be 720p.

I use all recommended setting in this page : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts

How can I see the 720p live streaming during live ?

ps : I use obs to do live streaming

Thanks a lot!

By the way, I also ask Facebook team for help, here is the link
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/346617485719667

Comment: Same problem faced today. Wasit like so in past, or you tried it for the first time?

Comment: I have used this api about 2 month, but this is the first time I have noticed the resolution problem.

Comment: Yep, our team has noticed it foe the first time the same day as you. Still it seemed to be known issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1268951003139861/
(Unfortunately your link to bug does not open a certain bug, or I would subscribe)